# How to add a go-top button in html exported from org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a large org-mode file. I publish it to html. and this html file is also very large, when I browse this file,it's really hard to navigate to the top of the page. so I want to add a go-top button to it. how should I modify the org file to implement this feature？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an "id:" link that refers to the top of your HTML page.

http://orgmode.org/manual/Links-in-HTML-export.html#Links-in-HTML-export